# Range-style iterators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, d

I am looking to improve my JavaScript functional programming skills. As an exercise, I would like to port to JS H. S. Teoh's famous loopless calendar printout program - explained here https://wiki.dlang.org/Component_programming_with_ranges in its original D implementation, and in a fine YouTube lecture https://youtu.be/mFUXNMfaciE by Eric Niebler in a C++ port.

I have tried using JavaScript's native iterators and generators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators, and come swiftly unstuck. I get the impression that these are insufficient for this task. In particular:

1. they don't allow non-destructive querying of the iterator's
       completed state,
2. there is no mechanism to clone an iterator.

I have had a quick look at RxJs http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ with a view to using it for this purpose. I am concerned that it would take a huge amount of learning and is vast overkill, is not really designed to tackle the problem that I have (this is not an asynchronous problem, etc), and for all I know might not work.

My questions are:

1. Is RxJs a reasonable approach to emulating range-style iterators in JS?
2. If the answer to 1. above is 'no', what would be a better a library or approach?

Comment: _"Is RxJs a reasonable approach to emulating range-style iterators in JS?"_ - no it is not a reasonable approach. _"and come swiftly unstuck. I get the impression that these are insufficient for this task. In particular:"_ - why do you think you need either of those capabilities?

Comment: " why do you think you need either of those capabilities?" Required by the calendar program, as described in my first citation.

Comment: There is no need to map the D solution space directly onto the JavaScript solution space. Also, "cloning" an iterator in JavaScript is simple: `var other = [...iterator]`.

Comment: "There is no need to map the D solution space directly onto the JavaScript solution space" No, but I wish to emulate the effect of the original (to write the calendar program without ifs, loops of redundant buffering). It has, after all, been done to C++.

""cloning" an iterator in JavaScript is simple" Does that work if the iterated thing is not an array? I got the impression from this ref https://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-would-we-copy-an-iterator it is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript supports functions as first-class data, so you can abstract your own toys with ease. Below we invent our own [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) (immutable) iterators using abstractions of our making, `Yield` and `Return`. [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is used to avoid duplicate computation of an iterator's next value.

Our persistent iterators will behave almost identically to their native JS counterparts, only they will be immutable! The `done`, `value`, and `next` properties should feel familiar.

```js
const Memo = (f, memo) => () =>
  memo === undefined
    ? (memo = f (), memo)
    : memo

const Yield = (value, next = Return) =>
  ({ done: false, value, next: Memo (next) })
  
const Return = value =>
  ({ done: true, value })

const Range = (min = 0, max = Infinity) =>
  min > max
    ? Return ()
    : Yield (min, () => Range (min + 1, max))

const state0 =
  Range (0, 2)
  
console.log (state0.done)  // false
console.log (state0.value) // 0  
console.log (state0.value) // 0

const state1 =
  state0.next ()

console.log (state1.done)  // false
console.log (state1.value) // 1
console.log (state1.value) // 1

const state2 =
  state1.next ()

console.log (state2.done)  // false
console.log (state2.value) // 2
console.log (state2.value) // 2

const state3 =
  state2.next ()

console.log (state3.done) // true
```

But you're not meant to step thru the iterators using assignment, *recursion* is just what we need here

```js
const MappedIterator = (f, it = Return ()) =>
  it.done
    ? Return ()
    : Yield (f (it.value), () => MappedIterator (f, it.next ()))

const Generator = function* (it = Return ())
{
  while (it.done === false)
    (yield it.value, it = it.next ())
  return it.value
}

const square = x =>
  x * x

Array.from (Generator (MappedIterator (square, Range (0, 10))))
// => [ 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100 ]
```

Of course, because the iterators are persistent, we can step thru the same iterator multiple times

```
const ConcatIterator = (x = Return (), y = Return ()) =>
  x.done
    ? y
    : Yield (x.value, () => ConcatIterator (x.next (), y))

const it =
  MappedIterator (square, Range (1, 3))

Array.from (Generator (it))                      // => [ 1, 4, 9 ]
Array.from (Generator (ConcatIterator (it, it))) // => [ 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9 ]
```

Here's a complete code demo

```js
const Memo = (f, memo) => () =>
  memo === undefined
    ? (memo = f (), memo)
    : memo

const Yield = (value, next = Return) =>
  ({ done: false, value, next: Memo (next) })
  
const Return = value =>
  ({ done: true, value })

const Range = (min = 0, max = Infinity) =>
  min > max
    ? Return ()
    : Yield (min, () => Range (min + 1, max))

const MappedIterator = (f, it = Return ()) =>
  it.done
    ? Return ()
    : Yield (f (it.value), () => MappedIterator (f, it.next ()))

const ConcatIterator = (x = Return (), y = Return ()) =>
  x.done
    ? y
    : Yield (x.value, () => ConcatIterator (x.next (), y))
    
const Generator = function* (it = Return ())
{
  while (it.done === false)
    (yield it.value, it = it.next ())
  return it.value
}

const it =
  MappedIterator (x => x * x, Range (1, 3))

console.log (Array.from (Generator (it)))
// [ 1, 4, 9 ]

console.log (Array.from (Generator (ConcatIterator (it, it))))
// [ 1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9 ]
```

Comment: @Bergi coming from you, I’ll take that as an immense compliment ^_^

Comment: Well thinking closer about it I guess I also peripherally recognised the formatting of code. You have a rather unique layout (you may still take that as a compliment :-P)